# GitHub - Firebase deploy working directory

Tags: reactjs, git, firebase, workflow

How to specify folder name for the `Firebase` and `GitHub` workflows. Basically I have a `.github` folder where `.yml` files are stored but I also have `frontend` folder where I store my React.js src files and everything else that is needed.

Now when I push the changes I get this error:

```
npm ERR! The `npm ci` command can only install with an existing package-lock.json or
npm ERR! npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or
npm ERR! later to generate a package-lock.json file, then try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-03-29T10_09_41_940Z-debug-0.log
```

This is my `.yml` file:

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
"on":
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_REACTTASK_20C61 }}"
          channelId: live
          projectId: reacttask-20c61
          workingdirectory: ./frontend
```

How to make it that my `frontend` folder is a working directory, beacuse it now seems it is not

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `entryPoint` option

```yaml
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_REACTTASK_20C61 }}"
          channelId: live
          projectId: reacttask-20c61
          entryPoint: ./frontend
```

for more details see the [docs](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy#entrypoint-string)